# How to set data from JSON in Excel rows?

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-data-export in React JS for exporting JSON data to excel file.

```
<ExcelFile element={<a> Download</a>}>
  <ExcelSheet data={this.state.storeDetail} name="Data">
    <ExcelColumn label="Store" value="storeNo" />
    <ExcelColumn label="RR State" value="rrState" />
    <ExcelColumn label="Store Name" value="storeName" />
    <ExcelColumn label="City" value="city" />
    <ExcelColumn label="ZBM" value="zbm" />
    <ExcelColumn label="ZBM State" value="zbmState" />
    <ExcelColumn label="Cluster Manager" value="clusterManager" />
  </ExcelSheet>
</ExcelFile>
```

By using ExcelColumn  I am able to export data in excel columns. (Vertically)
[image]

What can I Do if I wants to set that data in Row.(Horizontally)

Comment: [Each object in the `data` array should have a property corresponding to the `value` of each `ExcelColumn`](https://github.com/securedeveloper/react-data-export/blob/HEAD/examples/simple_excel_export_01.md). That's not what you want?

Comment: No. I have to set some data in first row (Header) which is dynamically coming from API.

Comment: Instead of <ExcelColumn label="Store" value="storeNo" /> this I wanted to do something like <ExcelColumn label="storeNo" /> but it's not working.

I wish to set label dynamically not values

Comment: Ah, so your question is how to create the `ExcelColumn` components dynamically from data you get from an API?

Comment: @Tholle -- Yes .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render the `ExcelColumn` components dynamically with data in your state as well.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    labels: [
      { label: "Store", value: "storeNo" },
      { label: "RR State", value: "rrState" },
      { label: "Store Name", value: "storeName" },
      { label: "City", value: "city" },
      { label: "ZBM", value: "zbm" },
      { label: "ZBM State", value: "zbmState" },
      { label: "Cluster Manager", value: "clusterManager" }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ExcelFile element={<a> Download</a>}>
        <ExcelSheet data={this.state.storeDetail} name="Data">
          {this.state.labels.map(label => (
            <ExcelColumn
              key={label.value}
              label={label.label}
              value={label.value}
            />
          ))}
        </ExcelSheet>
      </ExcelFile>
    );
  }
}
```